# Prolog. Comparing elements in a list

Tags: prolog

I have a list of people that contains list of people that contains name+age.

```
person(bob, 20).
person(charlie, 15).
person(steve, 21).
person(david, 25).
```

I want to create a predicate oldest(List, Name) that will take a list of names and return a name of the oldest person in this list. Something like this:

```
?- oldest([bob,charlie,steve,david], Name).
Name = david.

?- oldest([bob,charlie], Name).
Name = bob.
```

As I understand - it should iterate through the list and compare age of everyone in it, but the problem for me is that you should get age first and then return a name.

How can it be done? Thank you in advance.

This is all I have right now:

```
%If person is older
maximum([X|Y], MaxName, MaxAge):-
    person(X, Age),
    Age > MaxAge,
        %Set MaxName to X, do not really understand how to do it
    maximum(Y,MaxName,Age).
    
%Skipping a younger person, passing current MaxName and MaxValue to the next element
maximum([X|Y], MaxName, MaxAge):-
    person(X, Age),
    Age =< MaxAge,
        maximum(Y,MaxName,MaxAge).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive definition must have at least one clause defining a **case base** and at least one clause defining a **recursive step**:

- For the case base, you can assume that the oldest person in a list containing only one person is that very person.
- For the recursive step, you can consider that the list contains at least two persons. In this case, you can **discard the youngest** of the two and proceed with the remainder.

```
% oldest(++ListOfNames, ?Oldest)

  oldest([Name], Name) :- !.
  oldest([Name1, Name2|Names], Oldest) :-
      person(Name1, Age1),
      person(Name2, Age2),
      (   Age1 > Age2
      ->  oldest([Name1|Names], Oldest)
      ;   oldest([Name2|Names], Oldest) ).

person(bob, 20).
person(charlie, 15).
person(steve, 21).
person(david, 25).
```

Tests:

```
?- oldest([bob,charlie,steve,david], Name).
Name = david.

?- oldest([bob,charlie], Name).
Name = bob.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use foldl/4 in library(apply):

```
oldest(People, OldestPerson) :-
    foldl(oldest, People, 0-nobody, _OldestAge-OldestPerson).

oldest(Person, Oldest0-Person0, Oldest2-Person2) :-
    person(Person, Age),
    (   Age > Oldest0
    ->  Oldest2 = Age,
        Person2 = Person
    ;   Oldest2 = Oldest0,
        Person2 = Person0
    ).
```

The "fold" predicate iterates over a list, passing a value through the iterations. In this case, the value is `OldestAge-Person`, which contains the oldest age so far and the person with that age.

Note that this predicate doesn't do what you expect if given an empty list (`[]`). In general, you need to decide what to do with edge cases - for example, you could do:

```
oldest(People, OldestPerson) :-
    foldl(oldest, People, 0-nobody, OldestAge-OldestPerson),
    OldestAge > 0 .
```